# C# large picturebox darkens on right side

Tags: c#, picturebox, shadow

I am currently developing a screensaver that simulates the iPhone lockscreen..
I am using some large picturebox to display the "header" and "footer" locations,
but they have a strange behavior: on the **right side** of the picturebox is a "shadow like thing" that darkens the picture. Here a screenshot (watch the right side):

[lockscreen](http://drop.buto.ch/30-2011/lockscreen.png)

I am sure that its not from the picture itself that I am using, as this is just a tile (1 pixel width) that fills the picturebox!

If you want to see it on your computer, you can get the screensaver from here: [iPhoneLS](http://stark.buto.ch/software)

Why does this "shadow" occur? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I like it better with the shadow.

Comment: it is not from my screen, I've heard it from other users too.
and ye, the shadow looks not that bad, I just want to know why it occurs / and how i might fix it

Comment: dude, that's what most developers call a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably set the `Image` property of the `PictureBox`? I believe the image scaling of the picture box in `StretchImage` mode is not very accurate and thus causes the artifact (which I just verified by taking a 1px wide part of your screenshot and scaling that to the entire width of my screen using a `PictureBox`). Try to set the `BackgroundImage` property instead (having `BackgroundImageLayout` set to `Tile`), which does not stretch the image. You don't need a `PictureBox` for that purpose though.